# GIS data in Sweden

Tags: population, boundaries, sweden

Does anyone know where to obtain GIS data relating to Swedish postcodes - shapefiles, population and point location data?  I'm interested in both open data and licenced (purchased) data if it is available?

Answer (score 1):

Lund University has a nice website with a list of sites with everything from static map, GIS data, images to fully interactive map services.

https://www.gis.lu.se/geographical-data/geographical-data-for-everyone

They also have a specifc agreement with swedish agencies to provide data to their students and staff. Not sure if it is your case but here is the link for that

https://www.gis.lu.se/geographical-data/geografical-data-for-university-students-and-staff