# Up-to-date Sweden geolocation of postcode

Tags: geolocation, sweden, postcode

I am trying to calculate distance between postcode in Sweden.
But Sweden is changing post codes every year since 2012, and no an open database is up-to-date.

*(Source : Here : https://www.postnummerservice.se/nyheter/postnummeraendringar-mars-2023)*

---

**Sources found with full addresses but not up to date:**

- http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/ (is often the source of all sources, and contains a lot of countries)
- https://pypi.org/project/pgeocode/
- https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/geonames-postal-code%40public/information/?flg=fr
- https://swe.postcodebase.com/taxonomy/term/1268?page=5
- https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/geonames-postal-code@public/export/?flg=fr
- https://www.aggdata.com/free/sweden-postal-codes
- https://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=170+62&country=SE

---

**Seems up-to-date but can't find a downloadable source:**
https://www.worldpostalcodes.org/l1/en/se/sweden/profile/postalcode/170-62
https://postal-codes.cybo.com/search/?q=170+62&pl=&i=&t=

---

The only up-to-date source seems to be: https://www.postnummerservice.se/ It is even used by https://www.postnord.se/ as only source of truth
**But is not free**

Comment: If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: This GIS.SE thread has some links, maybe something in there is of interest: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267797/gis-data-in-sweden

Comment: I have not found a postcode dataset in INSPIRE, but maybe you can find something from here: https://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/results.html?country=se&view=details&theme=none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no free source. There was a try to crowdsource postcodes a few years ago but it has closed down. [Twitter](https://twitter.com/pnruppror) [GitHub](https://github.com/postnummeruppror)

I can't find any source on the largest postcode in terms of area but I found 981 99 being 120km across. So any distance calculation will be very very rough.

Comment: Yeah, distance is another problem here, I can live with approximation in the distance, not with missing postal code :). I'll mark your answer as solution if no better answer in the next days